# How to use zmq on android

Tags: android, python, zeromq

I have a Kivy/python app that communicates with other devices on my home network using zmq. When I try to port to android I get the following message in logcat:

```
 ImportError: No module named zmq
```

I guess this means that zmq needs to be implemented o the android device.

I am a complete newbie when it comes to this. There are [resources](http://zeromq.org/build:android) that seem to point in the right direction, but this is all very low level and I'm not even sure it is what I need to do.

Can anyone point to a high level resource that might help me get my head around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by dumping zmq and coding in sockets (see [brilliant tutorial here](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/))

Remember to add

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

to buildozer.spec